# Upgrading to Ruby 2.1.3 on Mac OSx 10.9.5

Tags: ruby, macos, installation

Today I upgraded to Ruby 2.1.3 from 2.0.0 on Mac OSx 10.9.5. It turned out to be more difficult than initially expected. And since I wasted a hell lot of time I thought I share my experiences plus solution in case someone else hits the problem as well.

I have xcode + developer tools installed. I updated xcode this week as well - not sure if that was the reason why things suddenly didn't work. However, here are the facts:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.25.32 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ brew -v
Homebrew 0.9.5

$ git version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

Getting the latest version of Ruby and using it as default:

```
$ rvm install ruby
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.1.3
```

**Now the issue is that if I tried to check ruby version I got the following:**

```
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.1.3
Using /Users/georg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/georg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
```

In fact nothing was really working - I tried to reload RVM, reinstall, re-install and upgrade homebrew, etc.

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade

$ rvm reload
```

Reinstalled ruby

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.1.3
Already installed ruby-2.1.3.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.3
```

And many other solutions - however, it all did not do the trick.

So I checked if I have /usr/local/lib/libcloog-isl.4.dylib

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/libcloog-isl.4.dylib
```

Which didn't give anything back ...

Comment: things like `rvm` and `rbenv` make this entire process even easier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So the solution, which resolved the issue is to run the following:

```
$ brew rm cloog; brew install cloog
```

Ta-Ta. It all worked all of the sudden!

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually just worked for me too.  I was having the same issue.  However, what made you think of "cloog"?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with the binary version of Ruby 2.1.3 that RVM installs. Michal Papis, the maintainer of RVM, hasn't put fixing this at the top of his priority list at the moment. The correct solution is to reinstall Ruby 2.1.3 without the binary, like this:

`rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary`

See these RVM GitHub issues to see Michal's comments about this issue:
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3068

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3094