# Errors when trying "rails new" after a new install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm just getting started downloading all my programs. I ran into an issue I didn't understand that was resolved using [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183787/upgrading-to-ruby-2-1-3-on-mac-osx-10-9-5/26385504#26385504). It worked perfectly.

I then followed the basic instructions on [this page](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app) and when I got to step 4 `rails new test_app` I received the following error.

```
/Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

--Update after Brennans comments

```
gem install railties
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.4
Fetching: minitest-5.4.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.4.2
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.beta1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0.beta1
Fetching: activesupport-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.1.6
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: actionview-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-4.1.6
Fetching: rack-1.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.5.2
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.2
Fetching: actionpack-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-4.1.6
Fetching: thor-0.19.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thor-0.19.1
Fetching: railties-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-4.1.6
13 gems installed
Hansens-MacBook-Pro:railsbridge Hansen$ rails new test_app
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
/Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:235:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:326:in `bundle_command'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:344:in `run_bundle'
from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
Hansens-MacBook-Pro:railsbridge Hansen$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.7.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.3
1 gem installed
Hansens-MacBook-Pro:railsbridge Hansen$ rails new test_app
   exist  
identical  README.rdoc
identical  Rakefile
identical  config.ru
identical  .gitignore
identical  Gemfile
   exist  app
identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
identical  app/assets/images/.keep
identical  app/mailers/.keep
identical  app/models/.keep
identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
identical  app/models/concerns/.keep
   exist  bin
identical  bin/bundle
identical  bin/rails
identical  bin/rake
   exist  config
identical  config/routes.rb
identical  config/application.rb
identical  config/environment.rb
conflict  config/secrets.yml
Overwrite /Users/Hansen/railsbridge/test_app/config/secrets.yml? (enter "h" forhelp) [Ynaqdh]
```

Comment: run `gem install railties` and try again

Comment: Thanks. Alot of things happened, a bunch of 'create' messages but then lines like this: `/Users/Hansen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:235:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /Users/Hansen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:326:in `bundle_command'` I know I'm supposed to get a "Your bundle is complete!" message. I don't see that.

Comment: Are you sure you have bundler installed? `gem install bundler`

Comment: Ok, installed that and tried again. Now I don't get any 'create' messages. A bunch of 'identical' messages with one 'conflict' `conflict  config/secrets.yml` and the message "Overwrite /Users/Hansen/railsbridge/test_app/config/secrets.yml? (enter "h" forhelp) [Ynaqdh]"

Comment: Delete the already-half-generated project before you try to re-generate it.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to run the `rails` commands you need to install at least two Gems manually:

```
gem install bundler
gem install rails
```

When both gems are installed you are able to run:

```
rails new app_name
```

Where `app_name` will be the name of your app and it will generate all application files in a subfolder `app_name`. If that folder already exists you may want to choose another name.