# rails new myApp doesnt create directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to this and learning RoR. I'm on Windows machine and tried it in CMD as well as Atom with platformio-ide-terminal package. both doing same thing. Was looking all over internet but cant find what is wrong. Basically I use `rails new test_app` command and only getting this back:

```
create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
```

and no other directories. I tried to reinstall everything and install SQLite3 gem, etc. but nothing.

Comment: I am not into RoR on Windows, I guess you followed steps from guides like: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 ?

Comment: Check the comments/answers here. It might help. I think you have bundler issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26416692/10313894

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll try to reinstall whole thing first. Will let you know if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your Ruby and Reinstall it with this files:

1. [Git](https://www.git-scm.com/)
2. [Ruby](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)
3. [Rails](http://railsinstaller.org/en)

Comment: Updated bundle and need to update buybug to v. 11.1.1 but it needs ruby 2.4.0 and this one installed 2.3.3 for some reason. gem install ruby -v 2.4.0 doesn't work.

Comment: Right, I installed ruby 2.6.5 first and then rails with ruby 2.3.3. So reinstalled ruby 2.6.5, then it had "missing sqlite3" error, so used 'gem install sqlite3' - sorted, then had "missing node.js" error and installed node.js. Then said it was missing yarn, so installed yarn - still saying yarn not installed. It gives links where to download, so used them.

Comment: Right, so when tried to start a server it said its missing webpacker, use `rails webpacker:install`... but then it would say that yarn is wrong (v. 0.1.1)... found a solution. so had to go to **C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems** and delete **yarn** folder, then reinstall yarn v. 1.23.1 and then install webpacker... phew. now it creates project with no issues. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: and runs a server too - no issues