# Ruby -v dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib

Tags: ruby, dyld

I've been trying to run a script in the terminal and every time I do I get:

```
$ ruby directory.rb
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/claretrembath/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I realized that when checking `ruby -v` I am given the same output:

```
$ ruby -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/claretrembath/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems that when ruby is compiled, it will "opportunistically" link against `gmp`.  This can be disabled with the `configure` script's `--without-gmp` option. In fact, this is what homebrew's ruby package does, as of Sep. 2019 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43841)

Answer (score 41):

I just encountered similar issue and was able to resolve it following an answer from [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/829837).

```
brew update && brew install gmp && rvm reinstall 2.1.4
```

Seems this was an issue with `libgmp.10.dylib`.

Comment: Really the rvm reinstall isn't needed. At least in my case (same error message though).

Answer (score 30):

For `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib`

you need `brew update && brew install gmp`

Comment: Seems like pretty poor form of the Ruby maintainers to require a third party math library and not mention it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by including the brew's gmp directory when installing:

`rvm install ruby-2.2.5 --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix gmp)`

Answer (score 1):

Mine was solved with:

```
brew update && brew install gmp
brew upgrade npm
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by installing `libyaml` and `gmp` via Homebrew on a self hosted GitHub actions server without the need for `rvm` or `ruby` using this command `brew install gmp && brew install libyaml` to fix an error in `ruby/setup-ruby`:

```
 warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
...
 Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib' (LoadError)
```

Answer (score -3):

Looks like it is an issue with upgrading the Ruby version.

Try:

```
$ brew rm cloog; brew install cloog
```

This seems much like this similar issue: "[Upgrading to Ruby 2.1.3 on Mac OSx 10.9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183787/upgrading-to-ruby-2-1-3-on-mac-osx-10-9-5/26183788#26183788)"

Hope that works for you.