# How to fix "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib" permanently for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I updated my OS about 2 weeks ago, and since then I've been running into this issue:

```
> ruby -v            
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
[1]    65487 trace trap  ruby -v
```

A solution found here ([Ruby -v dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555902/ruby-v-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libgmp-10-dylib)) works for each terminal session, but not permanently. I am running OS 10.9.5.

This is what works temporarily:

```
rvm reinstall 2.1.4
```

This has no effect, other than update homebrew:

```
brew update && brew install gmp
```

How can I fix this permanently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded)

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to reinstall `ruby`, `gmp` and `rvm` packages to fix the broken dependencies, e.g.

```
brew reinstall gmp rvm ruby
```

<sup>Consider running `brew update && brew upgrade` before.</sup>

Then reinstall `ruby` as:

```
rvm reinstall 2.1.4 --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix gmp) --disable-binary
```

Then check by:

```
ruby -v
```

Make sure you're using the right `ruby` (check by: `which -a ruby`), if not, setup the right order for `PATH` variable in your startup shell scripts (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`).

Also make sure you're not overriding any `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` variables from the startup shell scripts (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`).

Related: [Ruby installation issues with RVM](https://superuser.com/q/820364/87805).

Answer (score 0):

A reinstall did it for me as well:

```
brew reinstall gmp ruby
```