# Ruby on Rails - dyld: Library not loaded: Abort trap: 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, shell

So I recently started using a new Mac (running macOS 10.15.7 Catalina), and had cloned one of my older Rails projects from GitHub that I'm continuing to work on. When I run **bundle install**, I receive this error in my CLI:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv-exec: /Users/user2/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle: /Users/user1/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv-exec: line 47: /Users/user2/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle: Undefined error: 0
```

Right off the bat, I knew that this must have something to do with the discrepancy under the *Users* directory, since I set my project up on my old Mac with my old user name *user1*, while I set my new user name on my new Mac as *user2*. After viewing this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912946/how-to-fix-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-gmp-lib-libgmp-10-dylib-pe), I tried updating and then upgrading homebrew using **brew update** and then **brew update**, but that did not work for me.

Additionally, when I run **ruby -v** to check which version of Ruby I'm using, I now get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/user1/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/libruby.2.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user2/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I also tried overwriting the older symbolic link with the newer one:

```
ln -sfn /Users/user2/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle
```

But that didn't work for me either. How can I replace this older path with the newer one to fix these issues?

Comment: Update: I navigated from the home path into the path as indicated by the error:

`/Users/user2/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin`

I then opened my text editor and proceeded to overwrite all instances of the old user name `user1` and replace them with the new user name `user2`.